# How to Filter Elementor Posts By a Custom Field's value in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type named "Courses" & a custom field in it named "Institution". I want Elementor posts to filter the "institution" custom field by "University of Pennsylvania".
*To show only those courses which belong to that university*

**Code I am trying:**

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/institute_query', function( $query ) {
$meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

// Append our meta query instead of overwriting all elementors own metaqueries
if($meta_query == ""){
$meta_query = array();
}

// Append our meta query
$meta_query[] = [
    'key' => 'course_institution',
    'value' => [ 'University of Pennsylvania', 'university of pennsylvania', 'University-of-Pennsylvania', 'university-of-pennsylvania', 'university_of_pennsylvania' ],
    'compare' => 'IN',
];

$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/institute_query', function( $query ) {
    
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

    // Append our meta query instead of overwriting all elementors own metaqueries
    if( !is_array( $meta_query ) ){
        $meta_query = array();
    }

    // Append our meta query
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key'     => 'institution',
        'value'   => [ 'University of Pennsylvania', 'university of pennsylvania', 'University-of-Pennsylvania', 'university-of-pennsylvania', 'university_of_pennsylvania' ],
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ];

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

});
```

Comment: Where do you put this code?

Comment: You can put this code in your active theme functions.php