# Filtering custom posts on Elementor using the value of a custom field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor, custom-fields

I am using the Reveal theme to create a listing website and I recently discovered the Advanced Custom Forms (Custom fields).

On my homepage, there is an Elementor block of this Reveal plugin that allows me to display custom posts.

I'd like to adapt an Elementor widget to filter out listings with a value of 1 in the "FreeListing" custom field (basically exclude them).

I saw that this link offered the solution : [How to Filter Elementor Posts By a Custom Field's value in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67482432/how-to-filter-elementor-posts-by-a-custom-fields-value-in-wordpress) To make a long story short, everyone adds this to `add_action`, according to my research, but I have never seen this in my home.

But in my code I don't see how to introduce this. Do you know if I'm editing in the wrong place, or if I can do it here?

```
<?php
namespace Reveal\Core\Elementor\Widgets;

use Elementor\Controls_Manager;
use Elementor\Widget_Base;

class Popular_Listings_TwoNoFreeListing extends Widget_Base {

    public function get_name() {
        return 'reveal_popular_listings_2';
    }

    public function get_title() {
        return esc_html__( 'Popular Listings No Free', 'reveal-core' );
    }

    public function get_icon() {
        return 'eicon-banner';
    }

    public function get_categories() {
        return array( 'reveal-core' );
    }

    protected function register_controls() {

        $this->start_controls_section(
            'general',
            array(
                'label' => esc_html__( 'General', 'reveal-core' ),
            )
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'title',
            array(
                'label'       => esc_html__( 'Title', 'reveal-core' ),
                'label_block' => true,
                'type'        => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                'default'     => __( 'Most Popular Grid', 'reveal-core' ),
            )
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'showposts',
            array(
                'label'   => esc_html__( 'Number Of Listing', 'reveal-core' ),
                'type'    => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                'default' => 6,
            )
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'orderby',
            array(
                'label'   => esc_html__( 'Order By', 'reveal-core' ),
                'type'    => Controls_Manager::SELECT,
                'options' => array(
                    'date'     => esc_html__( 'Date', 'reveal-core' ),
                    'id'       => esc_html__( 'ID', 'reveal-core' ),
                    'title'    => esc_html__( 'Title', 'reveal-core' ),
                    'name'     => esc_html__( 'Name', 'reveal-core' ),
                    'modified' => esc_html__( 'Modified', 'reveal-core' ),
                    'rand'     => esc_html__( 'Random', 'reveal-core' ),
                ),
                'default' => 'date',
            )
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'order',
            array(
                'label'   => esc_html__( 'Sort Order', 'reveal-core' ),
                'type'    => Controls_Manager::SELECT,
                'options' => array(
                    'desc' => esc_html__( 'Descending', 'reveal-core' ),
                    'asc'  => esc_html__( 'Ascending', 'reveal-core' ),
                ),
                'default' => 'desc',
            )
        );
        $this->add_control(
            'extra_class',
            array(
                'label'       => esc_html__( 'Extra Class', 'reveal-core' ),
                'label_block' => true,
                'type'        => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                'default'     => 'popular-listing',
            )
        );
        $this->end_controls_section();
        $this->start_controls_section(
            'style_section',
            array(
              'label' => __('Color Option', 'reveal-core'),
              'tab'   => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_STYLE,
            )
        );
        $this->start_controls_tabs( 'tabs_button_style' );
        $this->start_controls_tab(
            'tab_button_normal',
            array(
                'label' => __( 'Normal', 'elementor' ),
            )
        );
        $this->add_control(
            'icon_color',
            array(
                'label'     => __('Icon Color', 'reveal-core'),
                'separator' => 'before',
                'type'      => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::COLOR,
                'selectors' => array(
                '{{WRAPPER}} .cat-icon i' => 'background: {{VALUE}} !important',
        
                ),
            )
        );
        $this->add_control(
            'icon_color_two',
            array(
                'label'     => __('Icon Color Two', 'reveal-core'),
                'separator' => 'before',
                'type'      => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::COLOR,
                'selectors' => array(
                '{{WRAPPER}} .bg-d' => 'background: {{VALUE}} !important',
        
                ),
            )
            );
        $this->add_control(
        'rating_color',
        array(
            'label'     => __('Rating Color', 'reveal-core'),
            'separator' => 'before',
            'type'      => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::COLOR,
            'selectors' => array(
            '{{WRAPPER}} .property_item .list-rate' => 'background: {{VALUE}} !important',
    
            ),
        )
        );
        $this->add_control(
        'checkek',
        array(
            'label'     => __('Checked Icon Color', 'reveal-core'),
            'separator' => 'before',
            'type'      => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::COLOR,
            'selectors' => array(
            '{{WRAPPER}} span.veryfied-author:before' => 'background: {{VALUE}} !important',
    
            ),
        )
        );
        $this->add_control(
        'status_color',
        array(
            'label'     => __('Status Color', 'reveal-core'),
            'separator' => 'before',
            'type'      => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::COLOR,
            'selectors' => array(
            '{{WRAPPER}} .place-status.closed' => 'color: {{VALUE}} !important',
    
            ),
        )
        );
        $this->end_controls_tab();
        $this->start_controls_tab(
            'tab_button_hover',
            array(
                'label' => __( 'Hover', 'elementor' ),
            )
        );
        $this->add_control(
            'title_color',
            array(
                'label'     => __('Title Hover Color', 'reveal-core'),
                'separator' => 'before',
                'type'      => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::COLOR,
                'selectors' => array(
                '{{WRAPPER}} .proerty_text .captlize a:hover' => 'color: {{VALUE}} !important',
                '{{WRAPPER}} .listing-cat a:hover' => 'color: {{VALUE}} !important',
        
                ),
            )
        );
        $this->end_controls_tab();
        $this->end_controls_tabs();
        $this->end_controls_section();
    }
    protected function render() {
        $settings    = $this->get_settings_for_display();
        $extra_class = $settings['extra_class'];
        $title       = $settings['title'];
        $showposts   = $settings['showposts'];
        $orderby     = $settings['orderby'];
        $order       = $settings['order'];
        $args        = array(
            'post_type'   => 'rlisting',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'showposts'   => $showposts,
            'orderby'     => $orderby,
            'order'       => $order,
        );

        $listing_query = new \WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
<!-- ================ List Grid Style ======================= -->
<section class="<?php echo $extra_class; ?>">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Single List -->
      <?php
while ($listing_query->have_posts()) {
            $listing_query->the_post();
            ?>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <?php
echo do_shortcode('[classical-list-item]');
            ?>
      </div>
      <?php
}
        ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- ============================ Listings End ================================== -->
        <?php
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in clarifying

Comment: normally you would just supply the elementor loop wioth a query ID, and then use that to add an action - but you are creating your own widget - So I don't know.

Comment: I can do that, but where ? Have any link or suggestion ?